# Python Pandas to group values in 2 columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

A data frame like below. the names are in 5 groups, linking by the common in column A.

I want to group the names. I tried:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'A': ["James","James","James","Edward","Edward","Thomas","Thomas","Jason","Jason","Jason","Brian","Brian"], 
'B' : ["John","Michael","William","David","Joseph","Christopher","Daniel","George","Kenneth","Steven","Ronald","Anthony"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df_1 = df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(list)
df_1 = df_1.to_frame().reset_index()

for index, row in df_1.iterrows():
    print (row['A'], row['B'])
```

the outputs are:

```
('Brian', ['Ronald', 'Anthony'])
('Edward', ['David', 'Joseph'])
('James', ['John', 'Michael', 'William'])
('Jason', ['George', 'Kenneth', 'Steven'])
('Thomas', ['Christopher', 'Daniel'])
```

but I want one list for each group (it would be even better if there's an automatic way to assign a variable to each list)， like:

```
['Brian', 'Ronald', 'Anthony']
['Edward', 'David', 'Joseph']
['James', 'John', 'Michael', 'William']
['Jason', 'George', 'Kenneth', 'Steven']
['Thomas', 'Christopher', 'Daniel']
```

I tried `row['B'].append(row['A'])` but it returns `None`.

What's the right way to group them?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the output expected?

Comment: @Kyle, please see edited question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add values of `A` grouping column in [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with `.name` attribute:

```
s = df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(lambda x: [x.name] + list(x))
print (s)
A
Brian             [Brian, Ronald, Anthony]
Edward             [Edward, David, Joseph]
James      [James, John, Michael, William]
Jason     [Jason, George, Kenneth, Steven]
Thomas       [Thomas, Christopher, Daniel]
Name: B, dtype: object
```

Comment: I guess this is what OP wants. I thought he just wants to print the output.+1

Comment: @jezrael, glad to have your help again, sir! this' very good!

Answer (score 2):

You can try this. Use [**`pd.Series.tolist()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.tolist.html)

```
for k,g in df.groupby('A')['B']:
    print([k]+g.tolist())

['Brian', 'Ronald', 'Anthony']
['Edward', 'David', 'Joseph']
['James', 'John', 'Michael', 'William']
['Jason', 'George', 'Kenneth', 'Steven']
['Thomas', 'Christopher', 'Daniel']
```

The reason you got `None` as output is `list.append` returns `None` it mutates the list in-place.

Comment: @MarkK Glad, it was helpful. ;)

Comment: would you mind I change the choice of answer to jezrael's?

Comment: No you should accept his answer. ;) It would be more helpful to the community.

Answer (score 1):

try the following:

```
    import pandas as pd

    data = {'A': ["James","James","James","Edward","Edward","Thomas","Thomas","Jason","Jason","Jason","Brian","Brian"], 
    'B' : ["John","Michael","William","David","Joseph","Christopher","Daniel","George","Kenneth","Steven","Ronald","Anthony"]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    #display(df)
    df_1 = df.groupby(list('A'))['B'].apply(list)
    df_1 = df_1.to_frame().reset_index()

    for index, row in df_1.iterrows():
        ''' The value of  column A is not a list, 
so need to split the string and store in to a list and then concatenate with column B '''
        print(row['A'].split("delimiter") + row['B'])
```

output:

```
['Brian', 'Ronald', 'Anthony']
['Edward', 'David', 'Joseph']
['James', 'John', 'Michael', 'William']
['Jason', 'George', 'Kenneth', 'Steven']
['Thomas', 'Christopher', 'Daniel']
```